# Linear regulator with remote load sensing and voltage tracking

Tags: voltage-regulator

I am trying to design a linear regulator with following requirements:

1. (R1) Output current range: 0 to 1 A.
2. (R2) Output voltage range: 0.9 to 1.5 V.
3. (R3) Output voltage range is to be swept in 10-20 mV steps. I think it would be easier if the output voltage is set by an externally applied voltage reference. I do not see how to achieve this using regulators with an internal fixed reference with output voltage typically set by a resistor divider. It should be possible using a digital potentiometer IC. However I would prefer to keep it simple and avoid using a microcontroller to program the digital potentiometer.
4. (R4) True remote load sensing (Kelvin sensing). Kelvin sensing is needed because there is a current sense resistor of 50 or 100 mohm in series with the regulator output. Connecting traces and wires are expected to contribute 10 to 20 mohm.
5. (R5) The required accuracy/precision of the output voltage at the load is < 15 mV (or 1%).

The regulator is part of a custom/dedicated test bench.
The regulator and the load (device under test) are on separate boards. The distance from regulator to load is approximately 30 cm.
The source voltage for the regulator circuit is provided by bench power supplies. They deliver 0-8 V and 0-5 A. It is not an issue to use 2 or 3 of them if needed. However using bench power supplies to power the DUT would need too many PSUs and is not an option.
The load (DUT) draws a quasi constant current. I am not expecting large load transients. I plan to put large decoupling capacitors on the DUT board nevertheless to avoid stability issues.
The device under test is an IC with over 20 similar power rails. All the DUT supply rails are to be powered at the same voltage. Current must be measured separately for each supply rail. Thus I plan to duplicate the regulator circuit multiple times on the same board. I would like the design to be as simple and compact as possible and therefore I would prefer a solution based on an integrated circuit. However I would consider other options such as implementing a linear regulator from an op amp and a discrete pass element if no regulator IC fits my requirements.

How can I design a circuit that would provide both remote load sensing and voltage tracking?

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: Try shopping each of your questions online. I remember that circuit being published by National Semiconductor in the 80's and it is still available on line. Explain why R3 would not work?

Comment: Your question needs some work.  Nowhere in your question do you tell us the required accuracy/precision of the output voltage at the load.  Why do you need Kelvin sensing for only one amp of output current?  Also left out:  What is the source voltage for the regulated output; and, what are the available power supply voltages to run the regulator circuit?  Please update your question with these details.

Comment: Kelvin sensing works at DC but it can result in stability issues if the wires are long, which adds inductance... and it won't give the regulator a better transient response, so if your load draws a quasi constant current it can help but otherwise placing the regulator at the point of load makes it a lot simpler... More info would help.